# Qgis 3 - Rule-base labeling combining to backgrounds

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, rule-based

I have a pointlayer with no symbology, but is labeled by numbers 1-74. The labels is styled with a circle background. For some of the points I need to keep the circle, but add a small SVG-symbol to the lower right of the label.

I have no idea have to solve this, because as far as I see, I can only choose the circle OR the SVG file.

I have tried to make more labelrules to combine, but it only shows one of them.

The first rule on the pic below "Qr-kode"  =  'Nej' is the standard, and is working fine. The next rule  "Qr-kode"  =  'Ja' and "text = nr" is identic to the first, but goes for the points for which i need to add the SVG file. The last one where "text = tom" is the SVG file. But it only shows either the cicle label or the svg depending on zoomlevel.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The second and third rules are identical. You should add some other conditions.

Comment: yeah. I know they are identical, because the rules goes for the same points. The second is the white circlebackground, and the third has a SVG as background. But I need to put the SVG in front of the circle to combine them so they look like one label. 
I can't do it in one label, because I have to choose between either circle or SVG.

Comment: Duplicate your layer in the layer list, use label and circle background for the first and SVG symbol for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want two label styles to display simultaneously for a given rule - like stacking symbologies - then you need to keep in mind that by default, the QGIS label engine will try to prevent label collision/overlap as much as possible, unless you specify otherwise.

Try setting both `"Qr-kode" = 'Ja'` labels to 'Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels) so that they will both display even if overlapping.

If I'm interpreting your problem correctly (a screenshot of your actual label display and intended outcome would help), you want something like this - where the red apple is an SVG background?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need check the `Show all labels for this layer (including colligind labels)` option in `Rendering` section of labeling to allow show label on top of another.

[image]